# Is possible to not show the title of Appendix?

Tags: chapters

In my thesis I have Appendix B with some stuff. Following I want to create a new Appendix (for example C) with the PDF loaded (see Figure). Cause the name APPENDIX C is already in the Figure I don't want to show it up in the chapter header. However I need it in the table of contents.

Is this possible?

[image]

Here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
blabla \ref{app:B}

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{}
    \label{Appendix B}
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix~\ref{app:C}: C}
    \label{app:B}
    \includepdf[pages=1,fitpaper]{Figures/samplepdf.pdf}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sort of the opposite of \section*.  Hyperref has a \phantomsection (page 33 of manual), or you could just use \refstepcounter{section} and \addcontentsline...

Comment: thank you @JohnKormylo can you add an example?

Comment: It would help to have a Minimal Working Example so that I know what document class etc. are being used.

Comment: @JohnKormylo i edited the question, tnks!

Comment: It seems \phantomsection is for sections only, not chapters.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for report class.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter[Title for TOC and header]{}
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 

    \clearpage
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \chaptermark{Title for header}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{\thechapter}Title for TOC}
    %\includepdf[pages=1,fitpaper]{Figures/samplepdf.pdf}% file not provided
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.5\textheight}% replacment

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: and for report class? if i try this code in my thesis i see the Contents empty.. @John Kormylo

Comment: I revise the solution using your MWE.  You can add a label after \refstepcounter,if you want one.  In your MWE you could have just used \thechapter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose an alternate approach: try to crop the pdf image you include, and leave the chapter names of your documentclass.

If you are interested only in the image you show in the screenshot, you can try:

```
\includegraphics[trim= <left> <bottom> <right> <top>,clip,width=\textwdth]{Figures/samplepdf.pdf}
```

where you should put between `< >` the lenght to crop from the included pdf (start with `10mm` for example and work your way down to the required frame).

`samplepdf.pdf` should be a one page pdf file. You can easily extract the desired page with some utility like `pdftk`